# DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r"C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\other\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

how to solve help

Opened page and  after loading the page immediately exits